# Access-Control-Allow-Origin, mailHandler.php, and forms.js

Tags: javascript, php, html, contacts

I have a really weird bug. I've been having trouble with this HTML5 template I've downloaded in terms of the contact form and MailHandler.php. I've done inspect element in Chrome and I keep getting the error "Failed to load resource: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.", even though the files are in the same directory. And I've definitely changed the PHP to add a header and replaced all the placeholder email addresses with my own, but I'm not getting anything in my inbox.

Thanks so much for all your help!

This is forms.js:

```
//forms
;(function($){
    $.fn.forms=function(o){
        return this.each(function(){
            var th=$(this)
                ,_=th.data('forms')||{
                    errorCl:'error',
                    emptyCl:'empty',
                    invalidCl:'invalid',
                    notRequiredCl:'notRequired',
                    successCl:'success',
                    successShow:'4000',
                    mailHandlerURL:'bat/MailHandler.php',
                    ownerEmail:'matthewkol186@gmail.com',
                    stripHTML:true,
                    smtpMailServer:'localhost',
                    targets:'input,textarea',
                    controls:'a[data-type=reset],a[data-type=submit]',
                    validate:true,
                    rx:{
                        ".name":{rx:/^[a-zA-Z'][a-zA-Z-' ]+[a-zA-Z']?$/,target:'input'},
                        ".state":{rx:/^[a-zA-Z'][a-zA-Z-' ]+[a-zA-Z']?$/,target:'input'},
                        ".email":{rx:/^(("[\w-\s]+")|([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)|("[\w-\s]+")([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*))(@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$)|(@\[?((25[0-5]\.|2[0-4][0-9]\.|1[0-9]{2}\.|[0-9]{1,2}\.))((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\.){2}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\]?$)/i,target:'input'},
                        ".phone":{rx:/^\+?(\d[\d\-\+\(\) ]{5,}\d$)/,target:'input'},
                        ".fax":{rx:/^\+?(\d[\d\-\+\(\) ]{5,}\d$)/,target:'input'},
                        ".message":{rx:/.{20}/,target:'textarea'}
                    },
                    preFu:function(){
                        _.labels.each(function(){
                            var label=$(this),
                                inp=$(_.targets,this),
                                defVal=inp.val(),
                                trueVal=(function(){
                                            var tmp=inp.is('input')?(tmp=label.html().match(/value=['"](.+?)['"].+/),!!tmp&&!!tmp[1]&&tmp[1]):inp.html()
                                            return defVal==''?defVal:tmp
                                        })()
                            trueVal!=defVal
                                &&inp.val(defVal=trueVal||defVal)
                            label.data({defVal:defVal})                             
                            inp
                                .bind('focus',function(){
                                    inp.val()==defVal
                                        &&(inp.val(''),_.hideEmptyFu(label),label.removeClass(_.invalidCl))
                                })
                                .bind('blur',function(){
                                    _.validateFu(label)
                                    if(_.isEmpty(label))
                                        inp.val(defVal)
                                        ,_.hideErrorFu(label.removeClass(_.invalidCl))                                          
                                })
                                .bind('keyup',function(){
                                    label.hasClass(_.invalidCl)
                                        &&_.validateFu(label)
                                })
                            label.find('.'+_.errorCl+',.'+_.emptyCl).css({display:'block'}).hide()
                        })
                        _.success=$('.'+_.successCl,_.form).hide()
                    },
                    isRequired:function(el){                            
                        return !el.hasClass(_.notRequiredCl)
                    },
                    isValid:function(el){                           
                        var ret=true
                        $.each(_.rx,function(k,d){
                            if(el.is(k))
                                ret=d.rx.test(el.find(d.target).val())                                      
                        })
                        return ret                          
                    },
                    isEmpty:function(el){
                        var tmp
                        return (tmp=el.find(_.targets).val())==''||tmp==el.data('defVal')
                    },
                    validateFu:function(el){                            
                        el.each(function(){
                            var th=$(this)
                                ,req=_.isRequired(th)
                                ,empty=_.isEmpty(th)
                                ,valid=_.isValid(th)                                

                            if(empty&&req)
                                _.showEmptyFu(th.addClass(_.invalidCl))
                            else
                                _.hideEmptyFu(th.removeClass(_.invalidCl))

                            if(!empty)
                                if(valid)
                                    _.hideErrorFu(th.removeClass(_.invalidCl))
                                else
                                    _.showErrorFu(th.addClass(_.invalidCl))                             
                        })
                    },
                    getValFromLabel:function(label){
                        var val=$('input,textarea',label).val()
                            ,defVal=label.data('defVal')                                
                        return label.length?val==defVal?'nope':val:'nope'
                    }
                    ,submitFu:function(){
                        _.validateFu(_.labels)                          
                        if(!_.form.has('.'+_.invalidCl).length)
                            $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url: /*"../bat/MailHandler.php"*/_.mailHandlerURL,
                                data:{
                                    name:_.getValFromLabel($('.name',_.form)),
                                    email:_.getValFromLabel($('.email',_.form)),
                                    phone:_.getValFromLabel($('.phone',_.form)),
                                    fax:_.getValFromLabel($('.fax',_.form)),
                                    state:_.getValFromLabel($('.state',_.form)),
                                    message:_.getValFromLabel($('.message',_.form)),
                                    owner_email:_.ownerEmail,
                                    stripHTML:_.stripHTML
                                },
                                success: function(){
                                    _.showFu()
                                }
                            })          
                    },
                    showFu:function(){
                        _.success.slideDown(function(){
                            setTimeout(function(){
                                _.success.slideUp()
                                _.form.trigger('reset')
                            },_.successShow)
                        })
                    },
                    controlsFu:function(){
                        $(_.controls,_.form).each(function(){
                            var th=$(this)
                            th
                                .bind('click',function(){
                                    _.form.trigger(th.data('type'))
                                    return false
                                })
                        })
                    },
                    showErrorFu:function(label){
                        label.find('.'+_.errorCl).slideDown()
                    },
                    hideErrorFu:function(label){
                        label.find('.'+_.errorCl).slideUp()
                    },
                    showEmptyFu:function(label){
                        label.find('.'+_.emptyCl).slideDown()
                        _.hideErrorFu(label)
                    },
                    hideEmptyFu:function(label){
                        label.find('.'+_.emptyCl).slideUp()
                    },
                    init:function(){
                        _.form=_.me                     
                        _.labels=$('label',_.form)

                        _.preFu()

                        _.controlsFu()

                        _.form
                            .bind('submit',function(){
                                if(_.validate)
                                    _.submitFu()
                                else
                                    _.form[0].submit()
                                return false
                            })
                            .bind('reset',function(){
                                _.labels.removeClass(_.invalidCl)                                   
                                _.labels.each(function(){
                                    var th=$(this)
                                    _.hideErrorFu(th)
                                    _.hideEmptyFu(th)
                                })
                            })
                        _.form.trigger('reset')
                    }
                }
            _.me||_.init(_.me=th.data({forms:_}))
            typeof o=='object'
                &&$.extend(_,o)
        })
    }
})(jQuery)
$(window).load(function(){  
             $('#contact-form').forms({
         ownerEmail:'matthewkol186@gmail.com'
         })
   })
```

This is MailHandler.php:

```
<?php
     header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');  
    ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
    error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
    $owner_email = /*$_POST[*/"matthewkol186@gmail.com"/*]*/;
    $headers = 'From:' .$_POST["email"];
    $subject = 'A message from your site visitor ' .$_POST["name"];
    $messageBody = "";

    if($_POST['name']!='nope'){
        $messageBody .= '<p>Visitor: ' .$_POST["name"] . '</p>' . "\n";
        $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
    }
    if($_POST['email']!='nope'){
        $messageBody .= '<p>Email Address: ' .$_POST['email'] . '</p>' . "\n";
        $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
    }else{
        $headers = '';
    }
    if($_POST['state']!='nope'){        
        $messageBody .= '<p>State: ' .$_POST['state'] . '</p>' . "\n";
        $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
    }
    if($_POST['phone']!='nope'){        
        $messageBody .= '<p>Phone Number: ' .$_POST['phone'] . '</p>' . "\n";
        $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
    }   
    if($_POST['fax']!='nope'){      
        $messageBody .= '<p>Fax Number: ' .$_POST['fax'] . '</p>' . "\n";
        $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
    }
    if($_POST['message']!='nope'){
        $messageBody .= '<p>Message: ' .$_POST['message'] . '</p>' . "\n";
    }

    if($_POST["stripHTML"] == 'true'){
        $messageBody = strip_tags($messageBody);
    }

    try{
        if(!mail($owner_email, $subject, $messageBody, $headers)){
            throw new Exception('mail failed');
        }else{
            echo 'mail sent you are a winner good job!!! yayyyyyyyyy';
        }
    }catch(Exception $e){
        echo $e->getMessage() ."\n you suck";
    }
?>
```

I also receive this error afterwards, although I don't know where the XML is coming from: "XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///Users/john/Documents/SkyDrive/Synapps/codester-free-responsive-bootstrap-template/codester/bat/MailHandler.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access."

Comment: By the way, I'm aware that "header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *')" is unsafe. I'm just using it for now to try and get rid of the Allow-Control-Allow-Origin error.

Comment: Looks like you're attempting to run things directly off the filesystem instead of through a web server.

Comment: Hi robertc, is that a problem? I heard that I might have to install XAMPP on my computer in order to run the PHP. Thanks!

Comment: I've added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're attempting to run things directly off the filesystem instead of through a web server.  Stuff requested with the `file://` protocol has different rules and security restrictions to stuff requested with `http://`.  Since you are at no point making any HTTP requests it's hardly surprising that you have no `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, hence the error message.

Your PHP script will do nothing if it is not being executed by a web server.  You will need to install a web server and PHP in order to make this work locally.